# Mongoose ORM async await

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

**anyone help me how can i manage this code using async and await feature. My requirement is after inserting 100 data then mongo database disconnected.**

```
var faker = require('faker');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping');
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    var Product = require('../models/product');



    async function insertDocument(){
        for(var i=0;i<=100;i++){
            try{
                var product = new Product({
                    imagePath:faker.image.image(),
                    title:faker.commerce.productName(),
                    description:faker.lorem.paragraph(),
                    price:faker.commerce.price()
                });

                product.save();
            }catch (err) {
                console.log(err);

            }
        }


    }
     insertDocument().then(function () {
      //  mongoose.disconnect();

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`product.save()` returns a promise.  If you want to insert the 100 documents serially (one after the other) use `await`.  If you want to insert the 100 documents in parallel you don't need `async` and should use `Promise.all`

## Sequential

```
async function insertDocument(){
    for(var i=0;i<=100;i++){
        try{
            var product = new Product({
                imagePath:faker.image.image(),
                title:faker.commerce.productName(),
                description:faker.lorem.paragraph(),
                price:faker.commerce.price()
            });

            await product.save();
        }catch (err) {
            console.log(err);

        }
    }

}
```

## Parallel

```
function insertDocument(){
    let promises = [];
    for(var i=0;i<=100;i++){
        var product = new Product({
            imagePath:faker.image.image(),
            title:faker.commerce.productName(),
            description:faker.lorem.paragraph(),
            price:faker.commerce.price()
        });

        promises.push(product.save());
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```